# Scipy curvefit RuntimeError:Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I want to make an logharitmic fit. But I keep getting the a runtime error:

> Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached
>   maxfev = 1000

I use the following script. Can anyone tell me where I go wrong? I use Spyder an am still a beginner.

```
import math
import matplotlib as mpl
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

#data
F1=[735.0,696.0,690.0,683.0,680.0,678.0,679.0,675.0,671.0,669.0,668.0,664.0,664.0]
t1=[1,90000.0,178200.0,421200.0,505800.0,592200.0,768600.0,1036800.0,1371600.0,1630800.0,1715400.0,2345400.0,2409012.0]

F1n=np.array(F1)
t1n=np.array(t1)

plt.plot(t1,F1,'ro',label="original data")

# curvefit
def func(t,a,b):
    return a+b*np.log(t)

t=np.linspace(0,3600*24*28,13)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, t, F1n, maxfev=1000)    

plt.plot(t, func(t, *popt), label="Fitted Curve")

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: you can also check this answer : [RuntimeError using SciPy curve fitting library with a large data set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47842131/7309662)

Answer (score 43):

Scipy's

```
     curve_fit()
```

uses iterations to search for optimal parameters. If the number of iterations exceeds the default number of 800, but the optimal parameters are still not found, then this error will be raised.

```
    Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800
```

You can provide some initial guess parameters for curve_fit(), then try again. Or, you can increase the allowable iterations. Or do both!

Here is an example:

```
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponenial_func, x, y, p0=[1,0,1], maxfev=5000)
```

p0 is the guess

maxfev is the max number of iterations

You can also try setting bounds which will help the function find the solution.
However, you cannot set bounds and a max_nfev at the same time.

```
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponenial_func, x, y, p0=[1,0,1], bounds=(1,3))
```

Source1: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6340

Source2: My own testing and finding that the about github is not 100% accurate

Also, other recommendations about not using 0 as an 'x' value are great recommendations. Start your 'x' array with 1 to avoid divide by zero errors.

Comment: In the mean time, this was fixed and both can be set at the same time

Answer (score 24):

Your original data is `t1` and `F1`. Therefore `curve_fit` should be given `t1` as its second argument, **not** `t`.

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, t1, F1, maxfev=1000)
```

Now once you obtain fitted parameters, `popt`, you can evaluate `func` at the points in `t` to obtain a fitted curve:

```
t = np.linspace(1, 3600 * 24 * 28, 13)
plt.plot(t, func(t, *popt), label="Fitted Curve")
```

(I removed zero from `t` (per StuGrey's answer) to avoid the `Warning: divide by zero encountered in log`.)

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np

# data
F1 = np.array([
    735.0, 696.0, 690.0, 683.0, 680.0, 678.0, 679.0, 675.0, 671.0, 669.0, 668.0,
    664.0, 664.0])
t1 = np.array([
    1, 90000.0, 178200.0, 421200.0, 505800.0, 592200.0, 768600.0, 1036800.0,
    1371600.0, 1630800.0, 1715400.0, 2345400.0, 2409012.0])

plt.plot(t1, F1, 'ro', label="original data")

# curvefit

def func(t, a, b):
    return a + b * np.log(t)

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, t1, F1, maxfev=1000)
t = np.linspace(1, 3600 * 24 * 28, 13)
plt.plot(t, func(t, *popt), label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why would a fitted plot end up linear when attempting to find the right fit for an exponential function (using non-linear least square regression)?

Answer (score 3):

`Curve_fit()` uses iterations to search for optimal parameters. If the number of iterations exceeds the set number of 1000, but the optimal parameters are still not available, then this error will be raised. You can provide some initial guess parameters for `curve_fit()`, then try again.

Answer (score 2):

After fixing your import statements:

```
#import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

your code produced the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
```

changing:

```
#t=np.linspace(0,3600*24*28,13)
t=np.linspace(1,3600*24*28,13)
```

produced the following output:

[image]