# Python: Fit error function (erf) or similar to data

Tags: python, scipy

I need to fit a special distribution of data with any available function. The distribution does not really follow a specific theoretical prediction, so I just want to fit any given function without great meaning. I attached an image with a sample distribution and a fifth order polynomial fit to show that this simple approach does not really work.

I know the distribution closely resembles an error function, but I did not manage to fit such a function with scipy...

I hope anyone has either a way to fit an error function to such a distribution, or maybe can suggest a different type of function I could fit to describe this distribution.

[image: Sample data]

Comment: The starting point is: what is the purpose of the fit?  For example, if you just want to be able interpolate/extrapolate your data --- then using something like a 'spline' would be fine.  If you're trying to get meaning from the specific functional form, then this might not be satisfactory.

Comment: I do want to interpolate the data, yes, but not in x-direction. I want, e.g. the x value at y position 90 and then an interpolation does not work since the answer is ambiguous. For now I have settled fitting a sigmoid function:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

with scope's curve_fit. The problem with this is that it needs quite accurate initial guesses on the parameters...

Comment: It might be more well behaved in log-space.  If you're sure the function is monotonic, you can simply to a spline of `x(y)` --- i.e. invert the relationship.  But a sigmoid function does seem like a nice way to go -- which is easily invertible analytically.

Comment: Unfortunately is not monotonic, but the sigmoid solves that. I have problems with getting a robust fit. I guess there is no other way to easily fit that function in a more robust way. curve_fit does not seem to do well when I change the input

Comment: Log-space didn't help?  (i.e. use `x -> log(x)` and `y -> log(y)`

Comment: Not really, it looks very similar ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can fit any function you want:

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
```

In case you want some function similar to erf, you can use for example:

```py
def func(z,a,b):
   return a*scipy.special.erf(z)+b
```

This will find the parameters a,b.

Answer (score 2):

Further fitting parameters might be helpful:

```
def func(x, a, b, z, f):
return a * scipy.special.erf((x - z)*f) + b
```

To prevent a runtime error, the number of iterations (default = 800) can be adapted with maxfev:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, maxfev=8000)
```

(See [Scipy curvefit RuntimeError:Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831763/scipy-curvefit-runtimeerroroptimal-parameters-not-found-number-of-calls-to-fun))

Comment: how does f correlate to "sigma" of the gaussian function?