# How to fit a gamma distribution to a set of coordinates in python

Tags: python

I have a set of x and y coordinates that I want to fit to a gamma distribution.

```
points = {8: 54.79,
          10: 92.76,
          12: 97.92,
          25: 175.84,
          50: 788.32,
          75: 1024.77,
          }
x_to_fit = np.array(list(points.keys()))
y_to_fit = np.array(list(points.values()))
```

I want to use these points to determine the optimal values of a gamma distribution so I try running the following line.

```
def gamma(percentiles, mu sigma):
    return stats.gamma.ppf(percentiles, mu, sigma)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(gamma, x_to_fit, y_to_fit)
```

When I run this I get the following error: RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 600.

My question is, how do I find the popt for the given coordinates and then once I find the popt how do I extrapolate y values given some x values (ie x = np.array([10,12,16,20,22,36,50,100,200,250,500,1000])?

Comment: Plot the initial guess and the function together. If they are too far apart, they are unlikely to converge

Comment: maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56573654/16785237) can help with your problem