# Is there still maxfev parameter in curve_fit? If not, how can we control the number of iterations performed?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

As of today, is there still this `maxfev` parameter in `curve_fit`?

If not, how to control the number of iterations that are performed while fitting?

I tried passing it in but seems it's just ignored.

I wonder if this parameter was removed and if so in which version?!  And mostly I wonder what's the recommended way now of controlling the number of iterations in the version that I have?

I am using an Anaconda distribution and its version of scipy is `1.7.3`.

See also

[Scipy curvefit RuntimeError:Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831763/scipy-curvefit-runtimeerroroptimal-parameters-not-found-number-of-calls-to-fun)

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6340

Comment: The argument is named  `max_fev` if you're  using `method='lm'`,  and `max_nfev` otherwise.  `method` defaults to `'lm'`  if no bounds are provided.

Comment: @Seon In which version? Where is this documented? Could you provide a link or something? I don't think there's underscore in the param name.

Comment: My bad, it should indeed be `maxfev` and `max_nfev`. I've checked the doc for 1.7.1 (it still works the same on the stable version though). See the documentation for the **kwargs parameter in the [official doc for `curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.7.1/reference/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). kwargs get passed to either `leastsq` (which uses maxfev) or `least_squares` (uses max_nfev). The `method` parameter of `curve_fit` determines which one gets called.